# What the origin of the name bug?

Tags: culture

I know it's a little off-topic, but what is the origin of the name "BUG" used in IT development when we have an issue with our applications ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because a butterfly was stucked in a computer and it created a bug. It is true !

Comment: Yes and it's why developers are using dark mode, because light attracts bugs.

Comment: And because it helps them C

Comment: Sources/citation needed.

Answer (score 0):

It was used by [Grace Hopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) in 1946:

> In 1946, when Hopper was released from active duty, she joined the Harvard Faculty at the Computation Laboratory where she continued her work on the Mark II and Mark III. Operators traced an error in the Mark II to a **moth** trapped in a relay, coining the term bug. This bug was carefully removed and taped to the log book. Stemming from the first bug, today we call errors or glitches in a program a bug

Reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_(engineering)

[https://ei.cs.vt.edu/~history/Hopper.Danis.html](https://ei.cs.vt.edu/%7Ehistory/Hopper.Danis.html)

Answer (score -3):

Acutally, Thomas Edison referred to a technical error as being a "bug" way back in 1878.

Comment: Sources/citation needed.